# Unable to connect to bootnode

Tags: substrate-node, validator

I have 1 live chain

Context:

- Archive node serves as the bootnode
- Having some pre-defined validators connected to the bootnode (`--bootnodes /ip4/13.215.176.156/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSCPiw5WquLQ1rZCbVUU8U95tgGU55EEuRZryxVJZyB7a --validator`
- The bootnode has 26 connected peers
- Network is still up

I have my instance, I join my live chain as an additional validator (using the same command as the pre-defined validators)

Issue:

- Peer count is `0`
- My node didn't sync the ledger

Questions:

1. Why am I unable to connect to the current bootnode, even though other pre-defined validators can establish a connection?
2. May I run another archive node without bootnode flag command?

Comment: peer count 0 means it can't see the bootnode (note also 0 network activity). If the public key was different it would tell you in the error message. So check you can ping the IP and check that the port is open and not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Adding `ws` in `--bootnode` flag

`--bootnodes /ip4/13.215.176.156/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWSCPiw5WquLQ1rZCbVUU8U95tgGU55EEuRZryxVJZyB7a`

I don't know why it works. My initial validators are running properly when I execute the same command without adding `ws`

My `polkadot-sdk` version is `0.9.36`